# Force disconnect from DataMapper (DataObjects adapter) before forking?

Tags: ruby, datamapper

Using DataMapper, in a process that forks children, I'm getting packet corruption, due to the DB connection still being open (and used) in the parent.  I want to force a disconnect and re-connect, as you're supposed to do when forking, but DataMapper does not look like it has even considered this use case.

Right now I'm going via a private API, and had to figure out a bit about the internals and its connection pooling to do this, so it feels wrong:

```
DataMapper.repository(:default).adapter.send(:open_connection).dispose
```

Does anybody know if there's a more "public" and correct way to do this?  I asked on the IRC channel, but nobody responded.

Answer (score 3):

I have had success with [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262135/force-datamapper-to-disconnect-from-postgresql/4262261) presented in another question, e.g.

```
# Disconnects an existing DataMapper Session
def disconnect!
  DataObjects::Pooling.pools.each do |pool|
    pool.dispose
  end
end
```